# Android SSL TLS connection to XMPP server

Tags: android, sockets, ssl, xmpp

I am trying to connect to an XMPP server requiring "Encryption (SSL or TLS)". I cannot use Smack or other third-party libraries (school project)

Here is my Java code to initialize an SSL socket :

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory=TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
socket = sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(HOST, PORT);
socket.setKeepAlive(true);
```

If I try to open the stream on the socket:

```
socket.getOutputStream()
```

I get this error :

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x76cb46a0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error

error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:766 0x72fb3d74:0x00000000)

at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:448)
```

Does anyone know where is the issue from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From having a short look at the [XMPP core specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3920#page-19) it does not look like you can simple use a socket and upgrade it immediately to TLS. Instead you have to first use some kind of `STARTTLS` command and only after that you can upgrade to TLS. This is similar to explicit TLS in SMTP, IMAP etc.

For more details please see the [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3920#page-19). Some shorter information you will find [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41470/xmpp-ssl-cipher-negotiation).

Comment: Indeed that explain the last part in the command :

openssl s_client -connect jabber.hot-chilli.net:5222 -starttls xmpp